# GMail API: Authentication required twice

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm running a app on Google App Engine which connects to the GMail API. In general this all works fine, however I have noticed that if I start a completely new session, the authorization is asking for authorization twice. Once from Google App Engine (see image below), and once through the regular Consent Screen as I would expect. What is initiating the first authorization and is there any way I can get rid of it?

[image: screenshot]

My code for authorization:

```
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
                    scope=settings.SCOPE)

class gmailAuth(webapp2.RequestHandler):
 @decorator.oauth_aware
 def get(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():
      self.response.out.write('success')
    else:
      self.redirect(decorator.authorize_url())
```

Comment: If you are doing the oauth yourself you shouldnt use the appengine page security setting.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean. How would this translate into the code above?

Comment: Sorry i cant look much at it now but it seems the issue is you have configured the page to use appengine user service for auth but you are also manually authorizing for a scope.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks. Thing is that the app engine authorization only comes on this page and I am using the webapp2 user model for user accounts, so not sure if that could be it.

Comment: Look if your xml is specifying page security settings or on the page code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that the @decorator.oauth_aware refers to the Google Account API, which I am not using. This is what is causing the screen to appear. That means that since I am using webapp2 authentication, I will have to refer to the non-GAE specific API authentication.